# Wordpress: Error connecting to database again and again

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Wordpress: Error reconnecting to the database

I am getting the error again and again that I am now tired. I am getting this error at least 2 times a minute or so during reload.

What I tried

Give custom value to pdo_mysql.default_socket and mysqli.default_socket

Took value from info.php file.

Changed localhost in wp-config to `127.0.0.1`

Reloading Apache2 and Mysql.. many times

It does connect with the database after some wait so... credentials are ok and I have also checked them personally.

Solutions pls? IT is consuming my a lot of time.. which makes me sad :(

Comment: Did you check the problem from mysql side? Can you share what mysql log says? In Linux environment you can find mysql log at `/var/log/mysql/error.log`

Answer (score 0):

There is numerous problems that can lead to that issue.

Your issue is not permanent, so it looks like network issue or mysql side related problem.

Try to repair database, using `STEP 3` from this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-debug-the-wordpress-error-establishing-database-connection)

Add that line to `wp-config.php`

```
define('WP_ALLOW_REPAIR', true);
```

Then go to `http://www.yousite.com/wp-admin/maint/repair.php` and follow dialog instructions as [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-debug-the-wordpress-error-establishing-database-connection) says.